Duplicate Removal within text[] per group in pgsql
I have something like a table with 2 columns component_names and component_types. The task is to remove the duplicates from the component_names for that component_types meaning same named component can be there across the types but not within.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('threshold_retry.threshold_details_id_seq'::regclass),
    component_type text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    component_names text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO test(id, component_type, component_names)
VALUES (1, 'INGESTION', '{ingestiona,atul, ingestiona, ingestionb}'),
       (2, 'INGESTION', '{test_s3_prerit, atul}'),
       (3, 'DQM', '{testmigration}'),
       (4, 'SCRIPT', '{scripta}'),
       (5, 'SCRIPT', '{testimportscript, scripta}'),
       (6, 'SCRIPT', '{Script_Python}'),
       (7, 'BUSINESS_RULES', '{s3_testH_Graph}'),
       (8, 'EXPORT', '{Export2}');

I am working towards the result being like this:
component_type  component_names
---------------------------------------------
INGESTION       {ingestiona,atul,ingestionb}
INGESTION       {test_s3_prerit}
DQM             {testmigration}
SCRIPT          {scripta}
SCRIPT          {testimportscript}
SCRIPT          {Script_Python}
BUSINESS_RULES  {s3_testH_Graph}
EXPORT          {Export2}

Where atul, ingestiona and scripta is getting removed.
I have written the python script for this but want to explore more in pgsql.
Tried a few queries, but nothing worked.
